# Cordova changing resolution?

Tags: html, angular, cordova

I create an android application using angular 4 and framework cordova.Ijust have one problem with screen resolutions

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LU2y.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkbQg.png)

I try to change the view port but still the same

```
<meta name="viewport" 
 content="width=device-width, 
 initial-scale=1.0, 
 maximum-scale=1.0, 
 target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />
```

Comment: I solve my problem using Scroll bar for the table this site can help you : it contain many example of scroll bar you can use it

https://mdbootstrap.com/javascript/smooth-scroll/